# VSCode automatically opens single subfolder in opened folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory-structure

so I have a folder structure like this [folder structure expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOEHG.png) which is is a single folder "folderB" containing interesting data in a parent folder "folderA". I want to move folderB around by drag-and-drop mechanism within the VSCode explorer. If I therefore open folderA it automatically expands folderB and displays all of its content (see first image), which becomes annoying when folderB contains lots of files, so the rest of my folder structure is pushed out of the explorer window. The problem seems to be that VSCode tries to open all folders, if they are the only element of a parent folder.

How to prevent this, i.e., how to tell VSCode only to open the folder that I clicked on? Like this [folder structure unexpanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xPM.png), which so far I only achieve by manually closing folderB.

I found the `explorer.compactFolder` setting, which only controls the inlining of a single child folder with its parent folder, but nothing to prevent the behaviour described above.